# C# MongoDB Case Insensitive Property

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, case-insensitive

Is it possible to set the property names to be case insensitive when filtering?

In my case, I am dynamically getting a document.  Let's say I am searching the users collection by first name.  In MongoDB, the standard naming convention is camelCase, "firstName".  But, in C#, the standard naming convention for a property is PascalCase, "FirstName".  So, when I am dynamically querying the collection and I do: `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(nameof(User.FirstName), someNameVariable)`, because MongoDB is by default case sensitive for property names, this never returns a document.

Sure, I could utilize a library like Humanize and do `nameof(User.FirstName).Camelize()`, but I have to be sure to find all instances in my code to add `Camelize()`.  All new code would need to do the same.  It would be nice if there were a setting to tell MongoDB to be case insensitive for property names.  Is there a setting to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using `Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.FirstName, someNameVariable)`? Since you have the model class, and within the model class, you can specify the name of the field for the property with `BsonElement`, when MongoDB .NET converts into query, it will based on the model class (schema) and BsonClassMap rule.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm getting the name through Reflection because the method doesn't know what exact model it will encounter.  Basically, it is told to use Users and to look at the FirstName.

Comment: From your previous message, you have a function to get the class and its field via Reflection. With this, you can try to get the custom attribute for the `BsonElementAttribute` from the property and build the filter. Unable to provide you further details without knowing what your code looks like. Otherwise, as you said, using Humanize library to build a camel case string for the property name will be much simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a setting for MongoDB similar to CamelCaseElementNameConvention that would allow me to tell Mongo to ignore the element's case.